# Как заставить работать indexOf на массиве данных из ячеек листа?

Tags: google-apps-script

Пытаюсь найти индекс элемента в массиве данных из ячеек листа - находит только первый элемент, остальные будто не видит. При этом индекс того же самого элемента в массиве этих же элементов, заданных явно, прекрасно находит.

Массив корректно заполняется всеми элементами, однако при сравнении содержимого массива данных из ячеек и массива этих же элементов, заданных явно, оказывается, что массивы не равны - хотя при выводе в текстовом виде видно, что они одинаковые.

При выводе в консоль ячейки представляются массив данных из ячеек представляет каждую ячейку как массив из одного элемента. Как это исправить, чтобы привести ячейки к обычному массиву, или как заставить работать на них функцию indexOf?
Ведь обычный перебор значений массива через for дает нужный результат, а ведь именно такой перебор [реализован в функции indexOf](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/array-find)?

```
function getIndex() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet;
  var searchcontent = "арбуз";
  var searcharray = ["арбуз","дыня","персик","черешня"];
  var searcharray2 = ss.getRange("A1:A4").getValues(); // содержит те же самые элементы
  i = searcharray.indexOf(searchcontent); // вернет 0 (все верно)
  i2 = searcharray2.indexOf(searchcontent); // вернет 0 (все верно), если искомое содержимое находится в массиве на первом месте, и -1 (не находит), если на любой другой
  isEq = searcharray == searcharray2 // вернет FALSE
  Browser.msgBox(searcharray + ' ' + searcharray2); // выведет одинаковые элементы
  Logger.log(searcharray2); // вернет [[арбуз],[дыня],[персик],[черешня]]
}
```

Comment: ну так у вас в searcharray2 массив массивов.  тогда как в searcharray массив строк.

ps: такое впечатление что вы спамите за google-apps-script. прекращайте.

Comment: нет, не спамлю, просто вопросов накопилось, потому сюда и пришел.

Comment: как сделать поиск в массиве массивов?

Comment: т.к. getValues [возвращает многомерный массив js](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) 
вам поможет [только перебор](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330061/815386)

меня лично удивляет, что это массив а не объект gas (скажем таблица) в которой можно было бы поискать по значению и получить массив координат. как-то так `a.getValues().findValue('test')` (получаем [0,2]);

Answer (score 2):

### Доступные типы данных в Таблицах

`Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `String`. Соответствуют типам в JavaScript.

### Range

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) предоставляет доступ на чтение и изменение диапазонов Таблиц. Может быть как отдельной ячейкой так и *последовательной группой* ячеек.

### getValue()

Метод [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) возвращает значение левой верхней ячейки диапазона. Т.е. результат всегда является одним из доступных типов.

### getValues()

Метод [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) возвращает прямоугольную сетку значений заданного диапазона. Представлен в виде двумерного массива, в котором, количество элементов соответствует количеству строк диапазона, а количество элементов каждого элемента строки соответствует количеству колонок диапазона. Содержит только доступные типы.

#### Общий случай

Диапазону `A1:C4`

```
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
|   |     A     |   B   |   C   |
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1 | Zoe       | 67233 | FALSE |
| 2 | Bella     | 14708 | TRUE  |
| 3 | Jacob     | 61457 | FALSE |
| 4 | Alexander | 60456 | TRUE  |
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
```

соответствует массив

```
[
    [Zoe, 67233.0, false],
    [Bella, 14708.0, true],
    [Jacob, 61457.0, false],
    [Alexander, 60456.0, true]
]
```

#### Частный случай. Одна строка

Диапазону `A1:C1`

```
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
|   |     A     |   B   |   C   |
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1 | Zoe       | 67233 | FALSE |
+---+-----------+-------+-------+
```

соответствует массив

```
[
    [Zoe, 67233.0, false]
]
```

#### Частный случай. Одна колонка

Диапазону `A1:A4`

```
+---+-----------+
|   |     A     |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | Zoe       |
| 2 | Bella     |
| 3 | Jacob     |
| 4 | Alexander |
+---+-----------+
```

соответствует массив

```
[
    [Zoe],
    [Bella],
    [Jacob],
    [Alexander]
]
```

#### Частный случай. Одна ячейка (не путать с методом `getValue()`)

Диапазону `A1`

```
+---+-----------+
|   |     A     |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | Zoe       |
+---+-----------+
```

соответствует массив

```
[
    [Zoe]
]
```

#### Примеры поиска индексов элементов, удовлетворяющих условию.

> Не надо ничего "сжимать" или искать некие "супер-пупер объекты gas", это Google. Что это вообще такое "gas"?

Следующий код возвращает карту всех вхождений определенного значения в диапазон

```
function mF() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheets()[0].getRange('A:D').getValues();
    var search = 'Zoe';
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
            if (values[i][j] === search)
                res.push({
                    row: i + 1,
                    col: j
                });
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Поиск по заданному номеру колонки `j = 0`. Значение относительно.

```
function mF() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheets()[0].getRange('A:D').getValues();
    var search = 'Zoe';
    var res = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        //for(var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){
        if (values[i][j] === search)
            res.push({
                row: i + 1,
                col: j
            });
        //}
    }
    Logger.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

Поиск по заданной строке `i = 0`. Значение относительно. Если диапазон из одной строки, то `i` всегда равно `0`.

```
function mF() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheets()[0].getRange('A:D').getValues();
    var search = 'Zoe';
    var res = [];
    var i = 0;
    //for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
        if (values[i][j] === search)
            res.push({
                row: i + 1,
                col: j
            });
    }
    // }
    Logger.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

### Дополнение

Конечно, использование библиотек на JS для работы со списками делает код более читаемым и прозрачным, но суть работы не изменится.

Выражаю большую благодарность всем, кто дочитал до конца. Ответом на вопрос может быть код на примере

```
function mF() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheets()[0].getRange('A:D').getValues();
    var search = 'Zoe';
    var res = values[0].indexOf(search);
    Logger.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

Потому что это частный случай.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно "сплющить" массив-столбец. Эта задача в общем-то не специфична к  Google Apps Script.

```
searcharray = sheet.getRange("A1:A4").getValues().map(function(v) {return v[0]});
```

(На данный момент, Google Apps Script не поддерживает [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), а то можно было бы красивее сделать.)

Если бы работа шла с прямоугольным куском таблицы, то  сплющивать наверно не стоит: данные в разных столбцах скорее всего имеют разный смысл, и indexOf был бы неуместен. Перебор в цикле, как обычно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас массив строк

```
["арбуз","дыня","персик","черешня"];
```

а должен быть массив массивов (таким же как возвращает .getValues())

```
[["арбуз"],["дыня"],["персик"],["черешня"]];
```

тогда массивы будут одного типа и их сравнение должно быть корректным.